# How to assign Watermark property to a TextBox's Text in code behind (MahApps)

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

```
<TextBox
        Name="mytextBox"
        Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="User"
        Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" />
```

I have `ComboBox` and each index i want to change this `Watermark` accordingly.
Is it possible to change this `Property` via code behind ?

Comment: Is `mytextBox` in `DataTemplate` or directly in a `Window`?

Comment: Yes i can reach this controller from my form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `mytextBox` is not inside template or different name scope and you can access it by name in the code you can either use static method of `TextBoxHelper`

```
TextBoxHelper.SetWatermark(mytextBox, "New Value");
```

or set it directly

```
mytextBox.SetValue(TextBoxHelper.WatermarkProperty, "New Value");
```